# Use variables in payload

Tags: python, json, aws-api-gateway, python-2.x

I have the following payload that I wish to use to make a post request.  How would I reformat if I wanted each of the values for Age, Average Family Size, and City to be variables?

```
payload = "{\"Age\": \"50\",\n \"Average Family Size\": \"2.5\",\n \"City\": \"Washington\"}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good use for F-strings.

Assuming your variables are named `age`, `size`, and `city`:

```
payload = f'{"Age": "{age}",\n "Average Family Size": "{size}",\n "City": "city"}'
```

Python 2.7 old-fashioned `%s` string interpolation:

```
payload = f'{"Age": "%s",\n "Average Family Size": "%s",\n "City": "%s"}' % (age, size, city)
```

Also, by enclosing the entire string in single-quotes, you don't have to escape the double-quotes.

Comment: Assume I'm using python 2.7

Comment: @ben890  Updated for python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary and the json module, although, f-strings would be much better if you could use a more modern version of python:

```py
import json

def get_payload(age, family_size, city):
    return json.dumps({
        "Age": age,
        "Average Family Size": family_size,
        "City": city
    })

print(get_payload(21, 2, 'Washington DC'))
```

Output:

```
{"Age": 21, "Average Family Size": 2, "City": "Washington DC"}
```